# Rails 3: respond_to html, how can I add a CSS rule?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user's profile page that displays a list of posts from the user. It has buttons for "liked" posts and "saved" posts belonging to the user. I use javascript so when someone viewing the profile clicks the "liked" posts button a .highlight css class is added to the button and it changes color, to show that the "liked" posts are being displayed.

However, when I respond_to html it re-renders the user profile html.erb, with the lists of posts being the "liked" posts. But there is no way to add a .highlight class to the "liked" button. The only way I can see of doing this is creating a separate view for "liked" posts, and repeating all of the code on the user profile html.erb but with 1 added .highlight class on the "liked" button.

This seems like a very poor solution. How can I add a css rule with respond_to html, such as when respond_to html button.liked-posts {color: blue;}

Thanks for any suggestions!

```
  def likes
    @title = "Likes"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @likes = @user.likes.paginate(:per_page => "10", :page => params[:page])
    @posts = @likes
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render "users/show"}
      format.js { respond_with @likes}
    end
  end
```

Is there a way to make a helper method with a case statement depending on the params of the url? URL example /users/:username/likes or /users/:username/category/:category

Or can javascript somehow remember the element from a previous page that started the 'get' request? ANd use that to add a .highlight class?

Comment: You can use if else condition in views. In one case add a class named highlight.  To use if and else. U should have some instance variable which will say whether it is profile view or not

Comment: Are you suggesting something such as adding a variable @like_highlight = "present" to my 'likes' method. And then placing an if statement <% if @like_highlight.any? %> html w/ .highlight class, <% else  %> html without /highlight class? <% end %> Would this be process intensive if I had around a dozen of these type if else statements on a profile page?

Comment: Yes it would be long process. Other options is . Use js.erb so that u can place JavaScript code to add new class in view. Use js.erb instead of .html.erb

Comment: I do respond with js but this would be if a user opened the page in a new tab.

Comment: My 'likes' method responds to both html and js. I use a .js.erb for javascript but I render HTML incase someone opens the page in a new browser tab. I was looking for a solution for the html render

Comment: Some how js needs to be added to add new class. May it be if else condition or else script tag js in view. Otherwise u have to make a Ajax request to that view